# Snowflake - Would it be possible to drop, modify, replace the same table from two different roles?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

There is a table created by a Sysadmin. I would like both Sysadmin and Analyst role to be able to drop, modify, or replace the same table if possible.  I understand we can change ownership of the table, but if both roles can drop, modify, or replace the table, that would be great.

This ANALYST role has limited access to snowflake databases and has following grant privileges:

- USAGE (Databases)
- CREATE TABLE, CREATE VIEW and USAGE (Schemas)
- DELETE, INSERT, SELECT and UPDATE (Tables and Views)

Comment: There can only be one role granted ownership to database object(s) that can create / drop said object(s).  That can be a shared role of course, and if in the RBAC hierarchy is defined below Sysadmin, the User granted Sysadmin role could change its role to the one that has ownership to perform the create / drop.

Comment: Thank you @JimDemitriou.  Do you think creating a table with ANALYST role and grant role analyst to role sysadmin makes more sense than creating a table using sysadmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding Ownership: You are right, only one role can be the owner of an object at one particular point in time.

However, you can have several roles, which are able to DROP, MODIFY and REPLACE the same table. This can be achieved by either

- Assigning the same privileges to the roles with two separate GRANT statements
- Assigning Role A to Role B so that Role B is inheriting all the privileges from Role A

Comment: Thank you @Marcel.  That makes sense.  As a best practice, do you normally create tables with custom roles and grant the custom role to Sysadmin for a role hierarchy?

Comment: Yes, exactly this is the case